# Using zip file without extracting in java

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem  that, we have a `.zip` file that contains some text files. Now I'm using java to access that files. If it is not in the `.zip` file I can read and print on my console easily using `FileInputStream`.

But how to read a file from `.zip` file? I use `J2SE` only..

Comment: What have you tried so far? (maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146402/how-to-read-and-write-a-zip-file-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try a [ZipInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).  The interface is a little obtuse, but you can use `getNextEntry()` to iterate through the items in the .zip file.

As a side note, the Java class-loader does exactly this to load classes from .jar files without extracting them first.

Comment: +1 for being first with a correct answer. I prefer ZipFile myself, but either works.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx - Ah, I had forgotten about ZipFile.  I agree that it provides a slightly nicer interface.  But as you say, either one should work.

Comment: How can I add or remove files in a zip file without extracting it

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need is in ZipFile: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html. Google for examples on the web, and if you have specific problems then come back to SO for help.

(The link will eventually break; when it does simply websearch `java zipfile`.)